# Python/Bash Grepping ip's

Tags: python, bash, grep

I have a text file with such results

```
|                       | 14-22-36 +0800                                        |             |
| 1.1.1.1:2020  | Software 1.6.0.26                     | disabled    |
```

I want to remove all the lines such as the first line which don't have any string or numbers in the first part between the tow pipes ..

I also use this command to grep the ips only

```
os.system("grep -Po '([0-9]{{1,3}}\.){{3}}[0-9]{{1,3}}(?=:\d{{4,5}}\\b)' 1.txt)
```

such command greps both the ip and the version of the software as ips like this

```
1.1.1.1
1.6.0.26
```

I need to grep only the ips between the first tow pipes
my script is written in python . I need it any with grep or python
How to do that ?

Comment: Why use grep when you can use re ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '^\| \K[^|]*(?=:)' file
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
```